# display data of sqlite table

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm not able to disply the content of my sqllite table.  Instead of displaying the values its displaying address of it....help me with the same...

```
 public  List<databaseHandler> getAllContacts() {
        List<databaseHandler> contactList = new ArrayList<databaseHandler>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

//        return cursor;
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                databaseHandler handler = new databaseHandler();

                handler.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                handler.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                //contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(handler);
                
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
//
//        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're returning a list of `databaseHandler` objects and displaying them somehow. "Address of it" hints at the display mechanism using the default `toString()` implementation that outputs the object's class name and `hashCode()`.

To fix that, override `toString()` in your `databaseHandler` class to return a string representation you want to get displayed.

Comment: I tried that its not working....again its displaying 'com.example.app.databaseHandler@6f58822'. help me with this please.

Comment: That's the output of default `Object#toString()`- either you didn't override it, or your overridden version is returning the same.

Comment: okay thankyou so much...I got my mistake and now its working perfectly...